# Given PMF for $X$, find PMF for $X^2$

Tags: probability

So I have the PMF for $X$ given by:

$p(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0.1, & \text { if } x \in\{-1,0,1,2\} \\ 0.2, & \text { if } x \in\{3,4,5\} \\ 0, & \text { else }\end{array}\right.$

I have to find PMF for $X^2$. I can't find anything about this anything in my textbook which is Blitzstein and Hwang.

Comment: The probabilities for $X^2$ are zero unless $X^2 \in \{0,1,4,9,16,25\}$.  Can you work out the probabilities for each of those values? (They should add up to $1$)

Comment: So prob. for $X^2$ is 0.1 for $X^2 \in (0,1,4)$ , right?

Comment: Let me write it whole down. 2 sec. please.

Comment: If  $X^2 \in \{1\}$ then the prob. is 0.2. If this is correct then the rest of my work is also correct.

Comment: $\mathbb P(X^2=1)=\mathbb P(X=-1)+\mathbb P(X=1)=0.2$ is indeed correct